# JOptionPane YES/No Options Confirm Dialog Box Issue

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I've created a `JOptionPane` and it only has two buttons `YES_NO_OPTION` .

After `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` pops out , I want to click `YES BUTTON` to continue opening the `JFileChooser` and if I clicked `NO BUTTON` it should cancel the operation.

It seems pretty easy but I'm not sure where is my mistake.

Code Snippet:

```
if (textArea.getLineCount() >= 1) {  //The condition to show the dialog if there is text inside the textArea

    int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to Save your Previous Note First?","Warning",dialogButton);

    if (dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { //The ISSUE is here

    JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
    int saveOption = saveFile.showSaveDialog(frame);
    if(saveOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    try {
        BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(saveFile.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
        fileWriter.write(textArea.getText());
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You need to look at the return value of the call to `showConfirmDialog`.  I.E.:

```java
int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to Save your Previous Note First?","Warning",dialogButton);
if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
  // Saving code here
}
```

You were testing against `dialogButton`, which you were using to set the buttons that should be displayed by the dialog, and this variable was never updated - so `dialogButton` would never have been anything other than `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`.

Per the Javadoc for `showConfirmDialog`:

> Returns: an integer indicating the option selected by the user

Comment: wow it worked! I just started using `showConfirmDialog` and I didn't get it so well, although I read the Javadoc.  But now with my mistake and your explanation it cleared a lot of confusion. I will play with this more and see what can I come up with. THANKS!!!

Comment: @iMohammad, why don't you read the Swing tutorial?? The tutorial contains working examples, for all the questions you have been asking over the past few days.

Answer (score 44):

Try this,

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Your Message", "Title on Box", dialogButton);
if(dialogResult == 0) {
  System.out.println("Yes option");
} else {
  System.out.println("No Option");
}
```

Comment: What can I put instead of `this`? I am doing this in a static context.

Comment: you could put `null` which would center the dialog in the middle of your screen instead of the parent frame.

Answer (score 7):

```
int opcion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Realmente deseas salir?", "Aviso", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if (opcion == 0) { //The ISSUE is here
   System.out.print("si");
} else {
   System.out.print("no");
}
```

Comment: How is this different from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689130/7111561) which was posted long ago which is even better since using the `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` instead of `0`?